# PHP foreach loop is rendering an extra list item

Tags: php

I am getting extra item displayed in a `foreach` loop. I'm not able to find answers for my specific code below:

```
<?php
if(count($catArr['details'][$id])>0){
  $ik=1;
  foreach($catArr['details'][$id] as $pv=>$pArr){
      if($ik == count($catArr['details'][$id])){
          echo '<a class="set_color2 linehigh4 w_600 s_1-3" href="/products.php?pid='.$pArr['pid'].'&cid='.$pArr['cid'].'&p_id='.$pArr['id'].'">'.$pArr['pname'].'</a>';
      }else{
          echo '<a class="set_color2 linehigh4 w_600 s_1-3" href="/products.php?pid='.$pArr['pid'].'&cid='.$pArr['cid'].'&p_id='.$pArr['id'].'">'.$pArr['pname'].' </a>';
      }//end if
      $ik++;
  }
}
?>
```

The rendered HTML in browser below is just a snippet showcasing the middle a href as a problem area which is not providing any element, but still showing up as and empty link in browser [view the image attached***]  :-

```
<a class="set_color2 linehigh4 w_600 s_1-3" href="/products.php?pid=34&cid=38&p_id=17">347 </a>

<a class="set_color2 linehigh4 w_600 s_1-3" href="/products.php?pid=34&cid=39&p_id=">  </a>

<a class="set_color2 linehigh4 w_600 s_1-3" href="/products.php?pid=34&cid=40&p_id=18">409 </a>
```

image attachment*** [ https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HEJKFOALSMDAuuRF_0KcgXVlUYmkFAaA/view?usp=sharing  ]

Comment: What is the value of `$catArr['details'][$id]` such as with `var_export`.  My guess you have an empty item in your array.  `$pArr['pid'] = ''`

Comment: You are right -'ArtisticPhoenix' those are the categories ( Stainless Steel ) under which these numbers are. I found extra category that was created but never got deleted from the admin panel but it was existing in the database. I had to go into the database and manually deleted that category and that has fixed the problem for now.

Comment: Sure, glad to help.  I am not sure it really warrants an actual "answer" though.  I can post one if you really want me to, but I have to run at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the array. You're having a null or empty value in the fields correponding to 'id' and 'pname'.
You should avoid putting them in the array in the first place but if you can't help it then make a null check inside the loop to skip that item.

Here's a code snippet with a little refactor to clarify what it is doing since the only difference was an extra blank space for the last item.

```
<?php
  if(count($catArr['details'][$id]) > 0){

      $ik=1;
      $count = count($catArr['details'][$id]);
      $space = '';

      foreach($catArr['details'][$id] as $pv => $pArr){

          if($ik == $count){
              $space = ' ';
          }

          if($pArr['id'] != null && $pArr['pname'] != null){
            echo '<a class="set_color2 linehigh4 w_600 s_1-3" href="/products.php?pid='.$pArr['pid'].'&cid='.$pArr['cid'].'&p_id='.$pArr['id'].'">'.$pArr['pname'] . $space . '</a>'; 
          }

          $ik++;
      }
  }
?>
```